# PHP SQLSRV Is Not Recognising Results Returned Via SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have some dynamic SQL that I build in PHP (passing some values in from the frontend). My SQL code works when executed within SSMS and is follows:

```
$sql_string = '
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TableName =?
DECLARE @ColumnNames NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColumnNames =?
DECLARE @ColumnValues NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ColumnValues =?
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Command = "DECLARE @InsertedID TABLE(ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT INTO " + @TableName + " (" + @ColumnNames + ")
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @InsertedID
VALUES " + @ColumnValues + "
SELECT ID FROM @InsertedID"
EXEC SP_ExecuteSQL @Command; SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
';
```

I am then looking at returning the ID of the inserted record (there is a DEFAULT for NEWID() on the column) I am using the following code to do so:

```
if($query === false){
    if(($errors = sqlsrv_errors()) != null){
        foreach($errors as $error){
            echo $error['message'];
        }
    }
}
else{
    $array = [];
    $all_count = sqlsrv_num_fields($query);
    while(sqlsrv_fetch($query)){
        for($i = 0; $i < $all_count; $i++){
            array_push($array, sqlsrv_get_field($query, $i));
        }
    }
    if(!empty($array)){
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
}
```

The annoying thing is, I know this code works, as I use it for simple SELECT statements. So not sure why the SQL works direct in SSMS and returns the ID, but sqlsrv_num_fields, sqlsrv_fetch and sqlsrv_get_field all seem to not recognise the returned value.

I cant insert the ID via PHP, I need the DB to do this.

Comment: Does PHP insert ID or not, I'm confused with your saying at the end. Regardless of that, try placing `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning in order to ignore _rows affected_ messages.

Comment: @alalp thanks for responding. It did insert the ID the PHP code just wouldn’t recognised the returned ID. I actually ended up rewriting my query builder so I have insert and select functions that can be used across a range of different means.